# Python2.7: plotly with networkx; Node attributes as long string (only visible through hover over the node)

Tags: python, plotly, networkx

I want to draw a network of gene interactions with plotly using a network built with networkx.  Lets assume that I have 10 nodes and for the sake of simplicity 9 edges connecting 1 node to all other 9 nodes.

I would like the keep the node labels visible as genes (say EGFR, TP53 etc..) and I would like the have some nodes to have an attribute specific to individual nodes. Now these attributes will be long strings (or a list object of few string elements) (I am OK with list object being converted to string as whole) and I would like the option to show the attribute associated with that list object when I hover over the node with mouse.

I would appreciate if I could set the margins of the pop up box (that comes when hover over the node) to be able to visualize the attribute nicely in a few newlines (not as a whole line of string, which would get out of screen)